# Parsing content with unicode decode error with python

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to scrape some info from tables from a website.  My codes are as follows:

```
import csv
import bs4 as bs
import requests
from lxml import html


url = "http://resources.afaqs.com/index.html?id={}&category=AD+Agencies&alpha="
data = []

for number in range(1,100):
    soup = url.format(number)
    r = requests.get(soup)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

    legalname = tree.xpath('//h2[@itemprop="legalname"]/text()')
    ownername = tree.xpath('//td[@itemprop="name"]/text()')
    locality = tree.xpath('//td[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()')
    pincode = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="postalCode"]/text()')
    addressregion = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()')
    telephone = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="telephone"]/text()')
    fax = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="faxNumber"]/text()')
    email = tree.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto")]/text()')

    legalname = [unicode(i) for i in legalname]
    ownername = [unicode(i) for i in ownername]
    locality = [unicode(i) for i in locality]
    pincode = [unicode(i) for i in pincode]
    addressregion = [unicode(i) for i in addressregion]
    telephone = [unicode(i) for i in telephone]
    fax = [unicode(i) for i in fax]
    email = [unicode(i) for i in email]

    data = {"legalname" : [legalname], "ownername" : [ownername], "locality": [locality], "pincode" : [pincode], "addressregion" : [addressregion],  "email": [email]}
    with open('output.csv','a') as file:
        writer=csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2'])
        for key in sorted(data.keys()):
            writer.writerow([key]+data[key])
```

Whenever this code encounters a unicode error value, it returns an error.  I have tried to convert the text to unicode, but it is not working.  Often I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

I tried to convert the

```
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
```

by adding

```
myparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = html.fromstring(r.content, parser=myparser)
```

How do I convert the xpath text value to utf-8 so that the data can be extracted.

Comment: What does the site tell you the right encoding is? Is there a `r.headers['content-type']` header? If there is a `charset` component in that header, try to use `r.text`.

Comment: HTML and server headers have always been tricky however; servers are often misconfigured, the default encoding for text is supposed to be Latin-1 (so `r.encoding` will be set to that in the absence of a charset parameter), and HTML files can specify their own encoding in a `<meta>` tag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters r.headers['content-type'] returns text/html

Comment: try 
a.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()

Comment: @DaniyalSyed: and what if the data isn't even UTF-8 encoded to begin with?

Comment: @Apricot: got a sample URL that causes issues? It may be that you just have to hard-code a correct encoding for this specific site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Yes that's a problem.. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: @DaniyalSyed: by figuring out the right encoding. That sometimes takes manual work, not every site declares this correctly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Thank you...when I changed `html.fromstring(r.content)` to `html.fromstring(r.text)`  i could download the content.  Still I have to do a lot of cleanup, which I was expecting...but the utf-8 error got resolved and the download happened.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I can accept your first comment as answer

Comment: @martijnPieters Oh okay thanks.. Is there any python library for auto detect encoding ? rather manual work

Comment: @DaniyalSyed: there is [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet), but take into account that all character detection method can only provide you with *guesses* based on statistical analysis.

Comment: @martijnPieters right.. is this a valid use case for machine learning domain ?  to train a model first then predict  the encoding given an input.

Comment: @DaniyalSyed: This is veering way off topic for comments. Feel free to have this discussion in the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay thanks